# unusual alteration in php behaviour during post of ajax data

Tags: php

I have up till now been using the following code (in relevant part) as my backend php for an ajax run webform. It works perfectly.

```
if(($ident) == "groupName") {
    $userInput = ucwords($_POST['groupName']);
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `groupName` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_groupName = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = NULL;
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_groupName);
}
```

And it nicely saves whatever the user places into the groupName text field. It also nicely returns the mysql field to NULL if the field is made blank. Which is what I want it to do.

However in order for this to work, I have been using an:

```
$ident = $_GET['ident'];
```

Value, passed along from the url. I want to get rid of this and make the system rely entirely on the posted data and keep the url clean. So I changed it to this:

```
if($_POST['groupName']) {
    $userInput = ucwords($_POST['groupName']);
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `groupName` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_groupName = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
        $report_groupName['errorText_groupName'] = NULL;
        $report_groupName['resultImg_groupName'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_groupName);
}
```

Which also works - almost. If someone enters in text, it'll function fine. If they enter in a blank space it'll return NULL as it is supposed to. But if they empty the text field and return nothing, nothing happens. The previous value remains unchanged. I don't understand why this is, and have tried making it work as an unaltered post (removing the ucwords() around the $userInput = ucwords($_POST['groupName']); but it has made no difference. Firebug tells me that "groupName" is indeed being sent with a nil value, so why won't this pick it up and behave accordingly, as it did in the earlier version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `if($_POST['groupName'])` will not be satisfied.

you may try use `if (isset($_POST['groupName']))` instead

Also I would replace

```
if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
```

with

```
if (empty(trim($userInput))) {
   $userInput = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matei, your answer did work. Your additional suggestion was also tried but this did not work, however once I modified it to:
if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
It did successfully work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 $userInput = trim($_POST['groupName']);
```

Comment: More explanation would be nice for the OP.

Comment: before checking if condition trim value then compare.